# How do I write a case statement that returns a message for a unique set of records based on a set of conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, select

Table1:

```
AccountID  AccountNumber  AccountTypeNumber
1          50             100
2          50             250
3          60             100
4          60             200
```

Table 2:

```
AccountNumber  AccountName  AccountStatus
50             School       Active
60             Work         Active
70             School       Active
```

Results Table:

```
AccountNumber  AccountVerification
50             Pass
60             Pass
70             Fail
```

I want the results table to return a `'Pass'` / `'Fail'` result for each unique `AccountNumber`. `'Pass'` for those with `AccountStatus = Active` in `Table2` AND have at least one record with an `AccountTypeNumber = 100` in `Table1`. All others, return `'Fail'`.

My current results only show `AccountNumbers` in Table1. They do not include `AccountNumbers` that are in `Table2` and not in `Table1`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Table1.AccountNumber 
    CASE 
        WHEN Count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY Table1.AccountNumber) > 1 
        THEN 'Pass' 
        ELSE 'Fail' 
    END AS 'AccountVerification' 
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.AccountTypeNumber = '100'
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.AccountNumber = Table1.AccountNumber
WHERE Table2.AccountStatus = 'Active'
```

Comment: Can there be account numbers in table 1 that are not in table 2?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CASE` construct with an inline correlated subquery to check if the relevant record exists in `table1`, like:

```
SELECT
    t2.AccountNumber,
    CASE WHEN
        t2.AccountStatus = 'Active'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM table1 t1
            WHERE t1.AccountNumber = t2.AccountNumber AND t1.AccountTypeNumber=100
        )
    THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS AccountVerification
FROM table2 t2
```

This will properly handle the use case where an account exists in `table2` but not in `table1`, and also avoid duplicates if there is more than one matching  record in `table1`. However if you have account numbers that occur more than once in `table2`, then you would need to use `DISTINCT` (since that case does not show up in your sample data, I did not use it, feel free to add it if needed).

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1224631fe02f5b8312cc1d0a04fe72c)** with your sample data returns:

```
AccountNumber | AccountVerification
------------: | :------------------
           50 | Pass               
           60 | Pass               
           70 | Fail
```

Comment: Thank you. There are duplicate account numbers in Table2 and it does appear the results are incorrect. It shows 'fail' for several AccountNumbers that have an AccountTypeNumber = 100 and AccountStatus = active. How do I add Distinct when I need to include other fields?  SELECT AccountName, AccountUniqueID, DISTINCT (t2.AccountNumber),
    CASE WHEN
        t2.AccountStatus = 'Active'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM table1 t1
            WHERE t1.AccountNumber = t2.AccountNumber AND t1.AccountTypeNumber=100
        )
    THEN...

Comment: @SLM: just replace « SELECT » with « SELECT DISTINCT », that’s all. Let me know if it works...

Answer (score 0):

With a left join from `Table2` to `Table1` excluding from `Table1` the rows `where accounttypenumber <> 100`:

```
select
  t2.accountnumber,
  case 
    when t2.accountstatus = 'Active' and t1.accountnumber is not null then 'Pass'
    else 'Fail'
  end accountverification
from table2 t2 left join (
  select accountnumber from table1
  where accounttypenumber = 100
) t1
on t1.accountnumber = t2.accountnumber
```